# Adding stringstream/cout hurts performance, even when the code is never called

Tags: c++, performance, logging, cout, stringstream

I have a program in which a simple function is called a large number of times. I have added some simple logging code and find that this significantly affects performance, even when the logging code is not actually called. A complete (but simplified) test case is shown below:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std::chrono;

std::mt19937 rng;

uint32_t getValue()
{
    // Just some pointless work, helps stop this function from getting inlined.
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        rng();
    }

    // Get a value, which happens never to be zero
    uint32_t value = rng();

    // This (by chance) is never true
    if (value == 0)
    {
        value++; // This if statment won't get optimized away when printing below is commented out.

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "This never gets printed, but commenting out these three lines improves performance." << std::endl;
        std::cout << ss.str();
    }

    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Just fror timing
    high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    uint32_t sum = 0;   
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        sum += getValue();  
    }

    milliseconds elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start);

    // Use (print) the sum to make sure it doesn't get optimized away.
    std::cout << "Sum  = " << sum << ", Elapsed = " << elapsed.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code contains stringstream and cout but these are never actually called. However, the presence of these three lines of code increases the run time from 2.9 to 3.3 seconds. This is in release mode on VS2013. Curiously, if I build in GCC using '-O3' flag the extra three lines of code actually *decrease* the runtime by half a second or so.

I understand that the extra code could impact the resulting executable in a number of ways, such as by preventing inlining or causing more cache misses. The real question is whether there is anything I can do to improve on this situation? Switching to sprintf()/printf() doesn't seem to make a difference. Do I need to simply accept that adding such logging code to small functions will affect performance even if not called?

**Note:** For completeness, my real/full scenario is that I use a wrapper macro to throw exceptions and I like to log when such an exception is thrown. So when I call THROW_EXCEPT(...) it inserts code similar to that shown above and then throws. This in then hurting when I throw exceptions from inside a small function. Any better alternatives here?

**Edit:** Here is a VS2013 solution for quick testing, and so compiler settings can be checked: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7b4UnjhhIiEamFyS0hjSnVzbGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with msvc 2013 and gcc 4.9. However, execution time varied enough to cover it on Windows between the first and subsequent calls to the compiled binaries (2984 vs 2546ms with the same executable), for which I blame filesystem caching. Does the effect persist over several runs of the program?

Comment: I still think it could be possible that this is due to branch prediction `if(value){value++;}` could conceivably be optimised to not contain any branching. Not that I am saying this is the case in this instance.

Comment: @Wintermute - Yes, I run it multiple times and always see 2.9... vs. 3.3... seconds. I added a VS2013 .sln download to the question to avoid any confusion over project settings.

Comment: @sjdowling - 'value *= value' shows the same effect... ideas for a better test are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I initially thought that this was due to branch prediction and optimising out branches so I took a look at the annotated assembly for when the code is commented out:

```
    if (value == 0)
00E21371  mov         ecx,1  
00E21376  cmove       eax,ecx  
    {
        value++;
```

Here we see that the compiler has helpfully optimised out our branch, so what if we put in a more complex statement to prevent it from doing so:

```
if (value == 0)
00AE1371  jne         getValue+99h (0AE1379h)  
    {
        value /= value;
00AE1373  xor         edx,edx  
00AE1375  xor         ecx,ecx  
00AE1377  div         eax,ecx
```

Here the branch is left in but when running this it runs about as fast as the previous example with the following lines commented out. So lets have a look at the assembly for having those lines left in:

```
if (value == 0)
008F13A0  jne         getValue+20Bh (08F14EBh)  
    {
        value++;     
        std::stringstream ss;
008F13A6  lea         ecx,[ebp-58h]  
008F13A9  mov         dword ptr [ss],8F32B4h  
008F13B3  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0B0h],8F32F4h  
008F13BD  call        dword ptr ds:[8F30A4h]  
008F13C3  push        0  
008F13C5  lea         eax,[ebp-0A8h]  
008F13CB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
008F13D2  push        eax  
008F13D3  lea         ecx,[ss]  
008F13D9  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],1  
008F13E0  call        dword ptr ds:[8F30A0h]  
008F13E6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],1  
008F13ED  mov         eax,dword ptr [ss]  
008F13F3  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+4]  
008F13F6  mov         dword ptr ss[eax],8F32B0h  
008F1401  mov         eax,dword ptr [ss]  
008F1407  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
008F140A  lea         eax,[ecx-68h]  
008F140D  mov         dword ptr [ebp+ecx-0C4h],eax  
008F1414  lea         ecx,[ebp-0A8h]  
008F141A  call        dword ptr ds:[8F30B0h]  
008F1420  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFFFFFFFh
```

That's a lot of instructions if that branch is ever hit. So what if we try something else?

```
    if (value == 0)
011F1371  jne         getValue+0A6h (011F1386h)  
    {
        value++;
        printf("This never gets printed, but commenting out these three lines improves performance.");
011F1373  push        11F31D0h  
011F1378  call        dword ptr ds:[11F30ECh]  
011F137E  add         esp,4
```

Here we have far fewer instructions and once again it runs as quickly as with all lines commented out.

So I'm not sure I can say for certain exactly what is happening here but I feel at the moment it is a combination of branch prediction and CPU instruction cache misses.

In order to solve this problem you could move the logging into a function like so:

```
void log()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "This never gets printed, but commenting out these three lines improves performance." << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

and

```
if (value == 0)
{
    value++;
    log();
```

Then it runs as fast as before with all those instructions replaced with a single `call log (011C12E0h)`.

Comment: Thank you, this is just the kind of detailed analysis I was hoping for. I agree that it's very hard to say exactly what is the problem, but moving the code to a separate log() function does appear to solve it. That said, in the general case I then need to pass a message as a parameter to that function, which still means creating a stringstream and building the message.

I don't think there is any way to make a function accept parameters like log("Number is " << num), so probably I'll fall back on C/printf() style va_args for this. I guess some things are just better done in C ;-).

Comment: @DavidWilliams There is a way you can do something similar in C++ with variadic templates, I've written an example [here](http://ideone.com/qB7dtr) which you can call in the style of `log("Number is ", 42);`

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know that was possible. I think I have all the bits and pieces I need for a solution now. I think it will be tidier than my old version too.